# Using Riverpod - how to properly implement automatic refresh/rebuild functionalty?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a simple app with list of `Task`s. Each `Task` is time bound.

```
@freezed
class Task with _$Task {
  const factory Task({
    @Default('') String title,
    required DateTime start,
    required DateTime end,
  }) = _Task;
}
```

Then I display the tasks using provider, e.g.:

```
class TasksController extends StateNotifier<List<Task>> {
  TasksController()
      : super(const []) {
    init();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    state = await GetTasksFromSomeRepo();
  }
}
```

I would like to show indicator that task is happening now, e.g.:

[image: mock diagram]

There exists a simple solution, where I do rebuild entire list of `Task`'s widgets every 1 second, using:

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
    setState(() {
        // this calls build method
    });
});
```

and in `build` method itself I check if `DateTime.now()` is within each `Task` "start/end" bounds.
This however seems like an inefficient approach.

###### Question:

1. How to do it with in more efficient way, ideally with help of a Riverpod?

Comment: Does your app comunicate with a backend?

Comment: @Axel It does not communicate with any API. To check if something is "in progress" it uses local time `DateTime.now()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more efficient solution using `setState`, here the `TaskContainer` widget is rebuilt at most twice.

```
class TaskContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const TaskContainer({
    required this.task,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TaskContainer> createState() => _TaskContainerState();

  final Task task;
}

class _TaskContainerState extends State<TaskContainer> {
  bool _inProgress = false;

  void updateProgress() {
    final now = DateTime.now();

    setState(() {
      _inProgress = now.compareTo(widget.task.start) >= 0 &&
          now.compareTo(widget.task.end) <= 0;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    updateProgress();

    final nowFromEpoch = DateTime
        .now()
        .microsecondsSinceEpoch;
    final timeToStart = widget.task.start.microsecondsSinceEpoch - nowFromEpoch;
    final timeToEnd = widget.task.end.microsecondsSinceEpoch - nowFromEpoch;

    if (timeToStart > 0) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: timeToStart), updateProgress);
    }
    if (timeToEnd > 0) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: timeToEnd), updateProgress);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final task = widget.task;
    final formatter = DateFormat('HH:mm');

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(task.title),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              if (_inProgress) const Text('In Progress...'),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(formatter.format(task.start)),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              Text(formatter.format(task.end)),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

An example page for testing it.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final repository = <Task>[
      Task(
        title: 'First',
        start: now,
        end: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute + 1),
      ),
      Task(
        title: 'Second',
        start: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute + 1),
        end: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute + 2),
      ),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => TaskContainer(task: repository[index]),
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        itemCount: repository.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT: Implementation with riverpod**

You can achieve the same by using a family of providers that take a task as a parameter. Your `Task` class should be immutable and override `== operator` and `hashcode`.

Provider:

```
final taskProgressingProvider = StateNotifierProvider.family<TaskProgressingNotifier, bool, Task>((ref, task) {
  return TaskProgressingNotifier(task);
});

class TaskProgressingNotifier extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  TaskProgressingNotifier(this.task) : super(false) {
    updateProgress();

    final nowFromEpoch = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
    final timeToStart = task.start.microsecondsSinceEpoch - nowFromEpoch;
    final timeToEnd = task.end.microsecondsSinceEpoch - nowFromEpoch;

    if (timeToStart > 0) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: timeToStart), updateProgress);
    }
    if (timeToEnd > 0) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: timeToEnd), updateProgress);
    }
  }

  final Task task;

  void updateProgress() {
    final now = DateTime.now();

    state = now.compareTo(task.start) >= 0 && now.compareTo(task.end) <= 0;
  }
}
```

Convert `TaskContainer` to `ConsumerWidget`:

```
class TaskContainer extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TaskContainer({
    required this.task,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Task task;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final formatter = DateFormat('HH:mm');
    final inProgress = ref.watch(taskProgressingProvider(task));

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(task.title),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              if (inProgress) const Text('In Progress...'),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(formatter.format(task.start)),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              Text(formatter.format(task.end)),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this approach with `timeToStart` is really smart, +1 from me. however I am really keen to know how to solve it with Riverpod approach. As with your approach we keep state in widget (`_inProgress` variable) while I'd like to have state lifted up. Thus question still remains.

Comment: @MaciejPszczolinski I updated my answer to include an implementation using riverpod.

Answer (score 1):

task_resolver.dart :

```
    enum TaskEvent {
      onProgrees,
      completed,
    }
    
    class TaskResolver {
    
      final Ref ref;
      TaskResolver(this.ref);
    
      Stream<TaskEvent> taskEvent() async* {

    // get from your provider,
    //ref.watch(taskController);

    //for simulation i just assign next day
    final taskDateCompleted = DateTime(2022, 12, 8);
    TaskEvent? current;
    while (true){
      final now = DateTime.now();

      if(current == null){
        //default value

        current = TaskEvent.onProgrees;
        yield current;
      }
      if(taskDateCompleted.isBefore(now) && current != TaskEvent.onProgrees){
        current = TaskEvent.onProgrees;
        yield TaskEvent.onProgrees;
      }
      if(taskDateCompleted.isAfter(now) && current != TaskEvent.completed){
        current = TaskEvent.completed;
        yield TaskEvent.completed;
      }
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    }

  }

}
    
    final taskResolver = StreamProvider.autoDispose<TaskEvent>((ref) => TaskResolver(ref).taskEvent());
```

on ui.dart:

```
class TaskPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TaskPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ref) {
    final status = ref.watch(taskResolver);
    return status.when(
        data: (taskEvent){
          print(taskEvent);
          return Text(taskEvent.name);
        },
        error: (_,__)=> const Text('error'),
        loading: ()=> const Text('loading')
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not comunicate with any API the only way to check for something in progress is, as you mention in the question, with a timer.

What you can do however is, instead of calling `setState`, change something in `task` (you could would create a new variable `state`) by accessing the `TasksController`.

If implemented correctly, that should trigger a state change that rebuilds only the right widgets, instead of the whole widget tree.

Comment: So is it correct to implement a timer inside controller while using Riverpod? I've never seen any similar example, thus my confusion

Comment: Yes, I think that it would be the best solution in your situation. I would however create the timer inside the widget class, in the initState method

Comment: Why inside widget? Isn't it part of a state thus belongs to state management? While widget is just part of presentation?

Comment: Correct, but if the widget is not intiated, there is no point into checking whether or not you need to update the UI. Hence, you really only need the timer to work when the widget is active.